# Using Angular $http service in node app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http

I'm developing a script in Node.js that needs to send multiple http requests. I'm really familiar with the way [Angular's $http service works](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). I like the use of promises and overall syntax, I know its advantages and disadvantages etc.

Can I in any way use Angular $http service in a Node.js app? I hope this doesn't sound too silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of self-promotion, I wrote an [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-client-factory) that provides promisified HTTP methods.

Comment: This module looks a lot like what Angular $http module is doing. And I can see you are using Bluebird. Nice thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: Good! One difference I just noticed that you'll run into is that where `$http` returns an error on non-2xx response codes, this will return success. Unfortunately, this isn't highlighted in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For promises like the ones in angular you can use [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Actually angular uses a subset of q.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Very nice to know!

Answer (score 2):

There's an NPM project for running AngularJS in node on the server located here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-server

That being said, you might want to take a look at Bluebird or just use ES6 promises in Node. Since Angular is a client-side framework it has a lot of things you don't need on the server.

Answer (score 1):

node has built in support for simple http requests from the [`http` module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) - however if you would like something a bit simpler and easier to manage I would reccoment the [Restify client API](http://restify.com/#client-api)

```
var restify = require('restify');

// Creates a JSON client
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
  url: 'https://us-east-1.api.joyent.com'
});


client.basicAuth('$login', '$password');
client.get('/my/machines', function(err, req, res, obj) {
  assert.ifError(err);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
});
```